# What can be "untracked files' in Git?

Tags: git

**Tracked files** are files in the last snapshot. And everything else is **untracked files**.

So what can be a untracked file, besides newly created files?

Thanks!

Comment: `.gitignore`d files and folders are untracked by default - you have to use "force" -f to add them (eg *.a pattern and you want to add lib3rdparty.a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I quite understand your question, but there's no requirement that each commit ("snapshot") includes *every* file that was in the working directory when that was created.  Your untracked file might have been in your working directory for a long time, and just never have been added.

Comment: Not really sure if that is right. Every commit is a snapshot of all the files, not just the ones modified / added in the commit. Each commit points to a tree object which is a snapshot of the entire tree.

Comment: @manojlds: But the snapshot of all files is only of all files "commited", not the unadded ones. So files maybe longer there than the git repository itself and can still be untracked.

Comment: @manojlds: That doesn't contradict what I said.  The implication of the OP's question ("what can be a [sic] untracked file, besides newly created files?") is that he / she doesn't think it's possible for untracked files to have existed before HEAD, and I'm contradicting that.

Comment: @Mark Longair - Sorry, nothing to do with the question. Just mentioning that, should have made that clear.